# How to update product properties with dispatch and PATCH request based on the selected language?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, use-state

I am trying to update a product based on the currently selected language.

In my case, the product is updated, but the object is changed in such a way that a language is missing and only the language in which it was updated is available.

One of the text fields look like this:

```
<TextField
  type="text"
  label="Title"
  name="product-title"
  value={title}
  onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
/>
```

I get the title from the store like this:

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState(product.title[lang]);
```

My submitHandler triggered by a simple button looks like this:

```
  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(
      updateProduct(product._id, {
        ...product,
        title: { [lang]: title },
      })
    );
  };
```

The updateProduct action looks like this:

```
export const updateProduct: ActionType<{ id: string, data: Partial<Product> }> = (id: string, data: Partial<Product>) => ({
  type: actionTypes.UPDATE_PRODUCT,
  payload: { id, data }
});
```

And I'm sending the PATCH request like this:

```
updateProduct = ({ id, data }: { id: string, data: Partial<Product> }) =>
  http.patch(`/api/products/${id}`, data);
```

The title property of the Products object looks like this before the update:

```
title: {de: "Nudeln", en: "Noodles"}
```

After the update suddenly like this ('de' becomes null):

```
title: {de: null, en: "Noodles Updated"}
```

I would like to have this result:

```
title: {de: "Nudeln", en: "Noodles Updated"}
```

My reducer for updating the product looks like this:

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action: ReturnType<ActionType>) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentProduct: { ...action.payload },
        loaded: true,
      };
}
```

So only the currently edited language should be updated and the other language should remain as it is.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem smartly?

Comment: Can you please also share the reducer code where you are updating the product ?

Comment: @usafder I added the reducer to my question.

Comment: Change the `dispatch(updateProduct(...))` call to `dispatch(updateProduct(product._id, { ...product, title: { ...product.title, [lang]: title } }));` and let me know if it works.